# UITableViewDataSource Functions?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm a newbie in swift, I stumbuled upon these two functions that must be used when calling UiTableViewDataSource:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

I can see what each function do, but I can't understand their structures. Like what about the parameter that each one takes? Why don't we give any values of these parameters? How does it determine that what indexpath really is?

Comment: You don't _call_ these methods. You implement and runtime calls _you_. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is the one responsible for calling them and picking the right index path according to what the table view needs or is visible at that time on the screen. Your only responsibility on the first one is to return the amount of elements that are in a given section and for the second one to dequeue the right cell and configure it with the data that corresponds to the index path that was passed in.